# phonegap android ajax load not functioning

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a simple mobile app built with jquery 2.0, jquery.mobile 1.3.1 and phonegap.

The application when starts, gets all its data from a txt file, which holds data in json format:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "content/datastructure.txt",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data)
        {
            app.data = data;
        },
        error: function (xhr, type)
        {
            alert("Failed to load data: " + type);
        }
    })
```

then the data stored in app.data are dynamically displayed in html using javascript.
inside data, I have some location information, which I use to display some places. I need to provide the user with the ability to navigate from his/her current position to the position of the place being displayed.

I get user's current position with these lines of code on deviceready event:

```
app.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
app.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
```

the problem is, when I deploy to android device the ajax load function is not working and the data are not loaded to the view. if I remove the lines which get coordinates, the app works fine on android devices.

Any suggestions out there what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the call to window.cordova and the problem was eliminated, although, this didn't lead to understand what was causing this problem.